# How much x-rays and heat is released by a high speed electron when collided with a surface?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrons, radiation, x-rays

We know that when an electron hit a target (surface) at very high velocity (or with high acceleration),it produces x-rays and heat.

So my question is how strong the x-rays and heat will be,if velocity of electron is 3×10⁶ m/s with voltage of 10kV.

I dont know if it is true or not but some websites claim that only 10% of energy is converted into x-rays and 90% to heat.

Is there any way to find the amount of x-rays and heat will be released.

Let the target material be a copper plate

Comment: But Beta radiation IS moving free electrons radiated out of a material!

Comment: Given the material, one can calculate the brehmsstralhung production from a particular incident electron energy.

Answer (score 3):

The question is posed with inaccuracy.

- Beta rays by definition are beams with electrons.
- When an electron moves at a 'constant' speed it produces no radiation. No charge at a constant speed does. When an electron is accelerated, it produces radiation. The higher the acceleration, the more the frequency of radiation produced. Therefore, you could produce x-rays with an accelerated electron beam (i.e. beta rays). Another way of producing x-rays is impinging high energy electrons on metal surfaces which causes electron transitions in the metal atoms thus producing x-rays.
- Heat is a concept of multiple particles and does not make sense for single particles. Single particles only have kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think any radiation is produced? If an electron is moving in a straight line at constant velocity it does not produce any radiation. If it is accelerated, it can produce electromagnetic radiation such as light, radio waves, or x-rays.

Answer (score 0):

High speed electrons (from a radioactive decay) are beta rays.  If high speed electrons collide with a metal surface, they can produce x-rays (and heat).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer by consulting a materials science textbook on the topic of *nondestructive testing by X-ray radiography.* There you will find the yield of X-rays as a function of target material, accelerating voltage and incident electron beam current.

It is true that most of the incident electron beam energy is wasted as heat in the target. For practical X-ray systems used for industrial radiography, the (usually copper) target must be cooled with internal water channels to prevent it from melting.

This is because the incident electron beam is *thermally generated* by a hot filament which necessarily furnishes a beam with a broad spread of energies, only a fraction of which are right for knocking an inner electron clean out of its orbit and thereby triggering the orbital decay process which emits an X-ray photon.

Furthermore, many of the incident electrons are inelastically scattered by their passage through the target material, which just heats the target and produces no X-rays.